# Get local drives without hitting floppy

Tags: c#, hard-drive

I'm looking for a way to scan for hard disks without incurring the 'floppy tax' of the system attempting to read the floppy drive to see if there's a disk in there.

*Important*: I know how to use `DriveInfo.GetDrives` to get just hard disks, but that involves filtering *after* the list has been created. What I want to do is filter *before*, if it's possible.

Comment: Yeah, "who uses floppies?" That's what I said too :)

Comment: Are we allowed to use a screwdriver as part of the answer... you know, to disconnect it and put something useful in its place?

Comment: @MarcGravell, it may yet come to that :) Honestly, I'm seriously considering it, as I'm apparently the only person who's bothered by it.

Comment: I wonder if you could disable it at the device level (devmgmt.msc)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this :

```
ConnectionOptions opts = new ConnectionOptions();
ManagementScope scope = new ManagementScope(@"\\.\root\cimv2", opts);
SelectQuery diskQuery = new SelectQuery("SELECT * FROM Win32_LogicalDisk WHERE (MediaType != 0 AND MediaType = 11 OR MediaType = 12)");

ManagementObjectSearcher searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher(diskQuery);
ManagementObjectCollection diskObjColl = searcher.Get();
```

Media types 11 and 12 are not floppy. You can find full documentation here : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa394173%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: I'm marking this one as the 'right' answer, even though I'm actually using the other (because it runs faster), but with a debatable assumption: that A and B are the floppy drives to be avoided.

Answer (score 1):

Not as such... Drive info simply has no functions to filter or exclude any types of drives during a getDrives call.

But maybe there's another way. 
(This is untested but maybe an idea: ) If you're simply looking for the availability of specific drives, you can instantiate the DriveInfo class with the name of a specific drive and see if that works?

Comment: Good point, I could start at C, and work up from there based on `System.Environment.GetLogicalDrives()`. Nice.

Answer (score 1):

The CD Drive And floppy Drive is not ready 
so you can  try this :

```
foreach (var dr in DriveInfo.GetDrives())
{
    if (dr.IsReady == true)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(string.Format("name : {0}   type : {1}", dr, dr.DriveType));
    }
}
```